# i made a code to see ip and mac addr in python but i have no idea on how to make the text appear in the gui

Tags: python, tkinter

i want to make this as an executable file which can be used as ann app on any computer to reveal their ip and mac address and i want the printed result to appear on the GUI but i have no idea how to do that.Here's the code:

```
from tkinter import *

import socket

import re, uuid

root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x250")

frame = Frame(root)
frame.bind("<Button-1>")
frame.pack()

def printName(event):
    hostname = socket.gethostname()
    IPAddr = socket.gethostbyname(hostname)
    print("Your computer name is:" + hostname)
    print("Your Computer IP Address is:" + IPAddr)
    print ("The MAC address is formatted and expressed in a less complex way : ", end="")
    print (':'.join(re.findall('..', '%012x' % uuid.getnode())))

theLabel = Label(root, text="IP-Mac",)
theLabel.pack()

button_1 = Button(root, text="show")
button_1.bind("<Button-1>", printName)
button_1.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use extra labels with placeholders:

```
theLabel = Label(root, text="IP-Mac",)
theLabel.pack()

ipLabel = Label(root, text="Gonna be the IP",)
ipLabel.pack()
...
```

In `printName` you can then set their text instead of printing:

```
ipLabel.config(text=IPAddr)
...
```

Comment: how do i make it into an executable file

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458048/how-can-i-make-a-python-script-standalone-executable-to-run-without-any-dependen